# Why recyclerview is not updating without reopening the app?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

So I am creating a todo app using room database in android kotlin and following mvvm architecture.For dependency injection I am using Hilt. My app's task list fragment has a recyclerview and a floating action button. By clicking floating action button a bottomsheet will pop up for inserting data. Data is adding to database successfully but not loading to recyclerview without removing it from recent apps and then reopen it. I tried to find out the problem but I didn't get anything. My code is given below:

**TaskEntity.kt**

```
package com.example.todos.model

import android.text.Editable
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "tasks")
data class TaskEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    val task: String,
    var isCompleted: Boolean = false

)
```

**TaskDao.kt**

```
package com.example.todos.db

import androidx.room.*
import com.example.todos.model.TaskEntity

@Dao
interface TaskDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun add(task: TaskEntity):Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks")
    suspend fun fetchTasks(): List<TaskEntity>

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteTask(task: TaskEntity)

    @Query("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun deleteTasks(id: Int)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(task: TaskEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getTaskBYId(id: Int): TaskEntity?


}
```

**TaskRepository.kt**

```
package com.example.todos.repositories

import com.example.todos.db.AppDatabase
import com.example.todos.model.TaskEntity
import javax.inject.Inject
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class TaskRepository @Inject constructor(private val db: AppDatabase) {

    suspend fun saveTask(task: TaskEntity) {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            db.taskDao().add(task)
        }
    }

    suspend fun getAllTask(): List<TaskEntity> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            db.taskDao().fetchTasks()
        }
    }

    suspend fun specificTask(id: Int): TaskEntity? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            db.taskDao().getTaskBYId(id)
        }
    }

    suspend fun updateTask(task:TaskEntity){
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            db.taskDao().update(task)
        }
    }

    suspend fun deleteTask(id: Int){
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            db.taskDao().deleteTasks(id)
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskListFragment**

```
package com.example.todos.ui.tasklist

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.todos.R
import com.example.todos.databinding.FragmentTaskListBinding
import com.example.todos.model.TaskEntity
import com.example.todos.ui.bottomsheet.AddTaskFragment
import com.example.todos.ui.bottomsheet.UpdateTaskFragment
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class TaskListFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_task_list) {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentTaskListBinding
    private val viewModel: TaskListViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var adapter: TaskListAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        initObservers()

        adapter = TaskListAdapter {
            adapteronClick(it)
        }
    }

    private fun adapteronClick(task: TaskEntity) {
        val bundle = Bundle()

        bundle.putInt("key", task.id!!)

        bundle.putBoolean("keyStatus", task.isCompleted)

        val bottomSheetUpdate = UpdateTaskFragment()
        bottomSheetUpdate.show(parentFragmentManager, "updating data")

        bottomSheetUpdate.arguments = bundle
    }

    private fun initObservers() {
        viewModel.taskItems.observe(this) {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        }
        viewModel.eventSuccess.observe(this) {
            adapter.submitList(adapter.currentList)
        }
        viewModel.eventDeleteSuccess.observe(this){
            adapter.submitList(adapter.currentList)
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = FragmentTaskListBinding.bind(view)

        initViews()

        initListeners()

        load()
    }

    private fun load() {
        viewModel.showTask()
    }

    private fun initListeners() {
        binding.addTask.setOnClickListener {
            val bottomSheetAdd = AddTaskFragment()
            bottomSheetAdd.show(parentFragmentManager, "Data is added")
        }
    }

    private fun initViews() {
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        binding.list.layoutManager = layoutManager
        binding.list.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

**TaskListViewModel**

```
package com.example.todos.ui.tasklist

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.todos.model.TaskEntity
import com.example.todos.repositories.TaskRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import javax.inject.Inject
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@HiltViewModel
class TaskListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: TaskRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _taskItems: MutableLiveData<List<TaskEntity>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<TaskEntity>>()
    }

    val taskItems: LiveData<List<TaskEntity>?>
        get() = _taskItems

    private val _eventSuccess: MutableLiveData<Boolean> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)
    }

    val eventSuccess: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _eventSuccess

    private val _eventDeleteSuccess: MutableLiveData<Boolean?> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Boolean?>(false)
    }

    val eventDeleteSuccess: LiveData<Boolean?>
        get() = _eventDeleteSuccess

    fun showTask() = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val tasks = repository.getAllTask()
            _taskItems.value = tasks
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _taskItems.postValue(listOf())

            Log.d("error", "somethig wrong happened")
        }
    }

    // Updating data
    private val _todo: MutableLiveData<TaskEntity> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<TaskEntity>()
    }

    val todo: LiveData<TaskEntity?>
        get() = _todo

    fun getTask(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val task = repository.specificTask(id)

            _todo.postValue(task)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("message-error", "Didn't get the task data")
        }
    }

    fun updateTask(id: Int, task: String, status: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val response = repository.updateTask(TaskEntity(id, task, status))

            _eventSuccess.postValue(true)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _eventSuccess.postValue(false)

            Log.d("message-error", "${e.message}")
        }
    }

    fun isValid(
        task: String
    ): Boolean {
        if (task.isBlank()) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    fun saveTask(
        task: String
    ) = viewModelScope.launch {
        if (!isValid(task)) {
            return@launch
        }

        try {
            repository.saveTask(TaskEntity(null, task, false))

            _eventSuccess.postValue(true)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("error", "Task is not added")
        }
    }

    fun deleteTask(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            repository.deleteTask(id)
            _eventDeleteSuccess.postValue(true)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("errorFound", "Data has been deleted")
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskListAdapter**

```
package com.example.todos.ui.tasklist

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.todos.databinding.ListItemBinding
import com.example.todos.model.TaskEntity

class TaskListAdapter(
    private val onCLick: (TaskEntity) -> Unit
) : ListAdapter<TaskEntity, TaskListAdapter.ViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent, onCLick)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val task = getItem(position)
        return holder.bind(task)
    }

    class ViewHolder(
        private val binding: ListItemBinding,
        private val onClick: (TaskEntity) -> Unit
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: TaskEntity) {
            binding.taskTv.text = item.task
            if(item.isCompleted)binding.completeBox.isChecked=true
            binding.completeBox.isChecked=false

            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onClick(item)
            }
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(
                parent: ViewGroup,
                onCLick: (TaskEntity) -> Unit
            ): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding, onCLick)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TaskEntity>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: TaskEntity, newItem: TaskEntity): Boolean {
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: TaskEntity, newItem: TaskEntity): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AddTaskFragment.kt**

```
package com.example.todos.ui.bottomsheet

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import com.example.todos.databinding.FragmentAddTaskBinding
import com.example.todos.ui.tasklist.TaskListViewModel
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class AddTaskFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddTaskBinding

    private val viewModel: TaskListViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initObserver()
    }

    private fun initObserver() {
        viewModel.eventSuccess.observe(this) {
            if (it == true) {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentAddTaskBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val task:String = binding.taskName.text.toString()
            viewModel.saveTask(task)
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**UpdateTaskFragment.kt**

```
package com.example.todos.ui.bottomsheet

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import com.example.todos.databinding.FragmentUpdateTaskBinding
import com.example.todos.ui.tasklist.TaskListViewModel
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class UpdateTaskFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentUpdateTaskBinding

    private val viewModel: TaskListViewModel by viewModels()

    private var taskId: Int = 0
    private var taskStatus: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            taskId = it.getInt("key")
            taskStatus = it.getBoolean("keyStatus")
        }
        initObservers()
    }

    private fun initObservers() {
        viewModel.eventSuccess.observe(this) {
            if (it == true) {
                dismiss()
            }
        }

        viewModel.todo.observe(this) {
            binding.taskName.setText(it!!.task)
        }
        viewModel.eventDeleteSuccess.observe(this) {
            if (it!!) {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentUpdateTaskBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        initListeners()

        getTask()

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun getTask() {
        viewModel.getTask(taskId)
    }

    private fun initListeners() {
        binding.saveBtn.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.updateTask(
                taskId,
                binding.taskName.text.toString(),
                taskStatus
            )
        }
        binding.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.deleteTask(taskId)
        }
    }
}
```